# Projection of i.i.d. Gaussians onto correlated Gaussian is bounded from below by chi-squared

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-normal-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, stochastic-ordering

Let $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \mathrm{Id}_k)$ and $\varepsilon_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\varepsilon_0 \neq 0$.
For some matrix or vector $A \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times p}$, let $P_A := A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T$ be the projection matrix onto the column space of $A$.
Write $1 = (1, \ldots, 1)^T \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$.
Then, the distribution of $\varepsilon^T P_A \varepsilon$ is $\chi^2(p)$, the distribution of $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon_0 \cdot \mathrm{1}} \varepsilon = \varepsilon^T P_1 \varepsilon = (\varepsilon^T 1)^2 / k$ is $\chi^2(1)$, and the distribution of $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon} \varepsilon = \varepsilon^T \varepsilon$ is $\chi^2(k)$.

Consider $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0} \varepsilon$, the square of $k$ i.i.d. standard Gaussians (this is $\varepsilon$) projected onto $A = \varepsilon + \varepsilon_0 \cdot 1 \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times 1}$.
If $\varepsilon_0$ is large, this is close to $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon_0 \cdot 1} \varepsilon \sim \chi^2(1)$.
If $\varepsilon_0$ is small, then this is close to $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon} \varepsilon = \varepsilon^T \varepsilon \sim \chi^2(k)$.

**To show**: $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0} \varepsilon$ is stochastically bounded from below by a $\chi^2(1)$ distribution.

This intuitively makes sense, as $\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0$ is "stochastically more aligned" with $\varepsilon$ than $\varepsilon_0 \cdot 1$.

Simulations strongly suggest this is true. Below are QQ-plots comparing the distribution of $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0} \varepsilon$ to the $\chi^2(1)$ (top) and $\chi^2(k=10)$ (bottom) distribution.
[image: qq-plots]

Some ideas:

- Write $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0} \varepsilon = \frac{|\langle \varepsilon, \varepsilon + \varepsilon_0 \rangle|^2}{ \\|\varepsilon + \varepsilon_0 \|^2}$
- By rotation, one can also consider $\varepsilon^T P_{\varepsilon + (\varepsilon_0, 0, \ldots, 0)^T} \varepsilon$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: > To show: +0 is stochastically bounded from below by a 2(1) distribution.

I will mark this in bold.

Comment: You could add a simple explanation in simple words. You are projecting $k$ iid normal distributed variables, onto a certain column space, and compute the sum of squares of the resulting projection. Typically this sum is chi squared distributed....

Comment: ... in your question you make this projection on something different. But what is it? What do you mean by $P_{\epsilon + \epsilon_0}$? And what is $\epsilon_0$, a constant a matrix or another random variable?

Comment: I edited the question. 

> But what is it? What do you mean by +0?

$\varepsilon_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a number.